# Make a subroutine faster

Tags: performance, optimization, fortran

In the main part of my Fortran code I have this lines

```
Gmat=0
do i=1,indCompMax
do j=(i-1)*useSymFlag+1,nsit-(i-1)*useSymFlag 
l=1
do while (G0poles(l,2)/=0)
Gmat(i,j)=Gmat(i,j)+real(G0int(i,j,l))/(omega(k)-G0poles(l,1))**G0poles(l,3)
l=l+1
enddo
enddo
enddo
call ExtendBySymmetry(Gmat)
```

This part is repeated several times in the code so I defined this subroutine

```
!=============================================================================
SUBROUTINE EvaluateFunc(matrixPol,matrixInt,z,matrix)
      use NAGmodule
      integer i,j,k
      REAL*8, DIMENSION(Npoles,3) :: matrixPol
      COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit,Npoles) :: matrixInt
      COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit) :: matrix
      COMPLEX*16 :: z

  do i=1,indCompMax
     do j=(i-1)*useSymFlag+1,nsit-(i-1)*useSymFlag 
       k=1
       do while (matrixPol(k,2)/=0)
         matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j)+real(matrixInt(i,j,k))/(z-matrixPol(k,1))**matrixPol(k,3)
         k=k+1
       enddo
     enddo
  enddo
  call ExtendBySymmetry(matrix)

end
```

The problem is that if I use this subroutine the evaluation of the output matrix takes much longer (around 5 times slower) than the same evaluation but made directly in the main part of the code.
How can I optimize the code and make the evaluation made with the subroutine faster?

UPDATE: Thanks for the reply. First, the operation  `**matrixPol(k,3)` is present also in the main code, I forgot to write it in the post.

For the comparison `(matrixPol(k,2)/=0)` there is no problem because actually starting from a certain position of the vector all the elements are exactly zero.

Computing the prefactor outside the `i,j` loop helped to speed the subroutine. And switching the two indices i and j has practically no effect. Here are the running times of the subroutine

All in the main part
1.688s

my old subroutine
19.063s

with `factor` outside the loop i,j
5.193s

Switching the indices i and j
5.281s

with dot_product
4.958s

But the subroutine is still more than 2.5 time slower.

Here is a minimal example:

```
    module  NAGmodule
    implicit none
    real*8,     allocatable :: hmat(:,:),eval(:),eigmat(:,:)
    real*8,     allocatable :: G0poles(:,:)
    complex*16, allocatable :: G0int(:,:,:)
    complex*16, allocatable :: Gmat(:,:)
    real*8,     allocatable :: omega(:)
    integer                 :: numpoles, halffillingflag, iter, indCompMax
    complex*16              :: omegaComplex
    real*8,  parameter      :: pi=3.141592653589793
    integer, parameter      :: out_unit=10
    integer, parameter      :: timeFag=1
    integer                 :: counti, countf, count_rate
    real                    :: dt
    integer, parameter :: Npoles=1000
    real*8, parameter  :: U=4
    real*8, parameter  :: omegamin=-20
    real*8, parameter  :: omegamax=20
    integer, parameter :: Nomega=1500000
    integer, parameter :: nsit = 4
    integer, parameter :: nup = 1
    integer, parameter :: ndw = 1
    integer, parameter :: PBCflag=1
    integer, parameter :: useSymFlag=1
    end module NAGmodule

    use nagmodule
    integer                 :: i,j,k,l,m,n,p,q
    REAL*8 t1,t2

    allocate(hmat(nsit,nsit),eigmat(nsit,nsit),eval(nsit))
    allocate(G0poles(Npoles,3),G0int(nsit,nsit,Npoles))
    allocate(omega(Nomega))
    allocate(Gmat(nsit,nsit))

    indCompMax=1

    hmat=0.
    do i=1,(nsit-1)
      hmat(i,i+1)=-1
      hmat(i+1,i)=-1
    enddo
    if (PBCflag==1) then
       hmat(1,nsit)=-1
       hmat(nsit,1)=-1
    end if

    call NAGdiag(nsit)
    eigmat=hmat

    do k=1,Nomega
      omega(k)=(omegamax-omegamin)/(Nomega-1)*(k-1)+omegamin
    enddo

    do k=1,nup
      G0poles(k,1)=eval(k) 
      G0poles(k,2)=-1
      G0poles(k,3)=1
    enddo
    do k=(nup+1),nsit
      G0poles(k,1)=eval(k)
      G0poles(k,2)=1
      G0poles(k,3)=1
    enddo


      do k=1,nsit
        G0int(k,k,k)=1
        if ((k==nup).AND.(abs(eval(k)-eval(k+1))<1e-15)) then
          G0int(k,k,k)=0.5
          G0int(k+1,k+1,k)=0.5
        else if ((k==nup+1).AND.(abs(eval(k)-eval(k-1))<1e-15)) then
          G0int(k,k,k)=0.5
          G0int(k-1,k-1,k)=0.5
        end if
      enddo

    do k=1,nsit
     G0int(:,:,k)=matmul(eigmat,matmul(G0int(:,:,k),transpose(eigmat)))
    enddo


    t1=0
    t2=0


    do k=1,Nomega
     omegaComplex=CMPLX(omega(k),0)
     call system_clock(counti,count_rate)
     Gmat=0
     call EvaluateFunc3(G0poles,G0int,omegaComplex,Gmat)
     call system_clock(countf)
     dt=REAL(countf-counti)/REAL(count_rate)
     t1=t1+dt

    call system_clock(counti,count_rate)
      Gmat=0
      do i=1,indCompMax
         do j=(i-1)*useSymFlag+1,nsit-(i-1)*useSymFlag 
           l=1
           do while (G0poles(l,2)/=0)
             Gmat(i,j)=Gmat(i,j)+real(G0int(i,j,l))/(omega(k)-G0poles(l,1))
             l=l+1
          enddo
         enddo
      enddo
      call ExtendBySymmetry(Gmat)
     call system_clock(countf)
     dt=REAL(countf-counti)/REAL(count_rate)
     t2=t2+dt
    enddo

   write(*,*)'time with subroutine',t1
   write(*,*)'time main',t2


    stop
    end

    !=================================================================================
    SUBROUTINE EvaluateFunc3(matrixPol,matrixInt,z,matrix)
          use NAGmodule
          integer i,j,k
          REAL*8, DIMENSION(Npoles,3) :: matrixPol
          COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit,Npoles) :: matrixInt
          COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit) :: matrix
          COMPLEX*16 :: z
          integer :: maxPoles
          COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(Npoles) :: factor


    maxPoles=0
    do while (matrixPol(maxPoles+1,2)/=0)
    maxPoles=maxPoles+1
    enddo 

      factor(:maxPoles) = (1.,0.)/(z-matrixPol(:maxPoles,1))**matrixPol(:maxPoles,3)

      do j=1,indCompMax  
         do i=(j-1)*useSymFlag+1,nsit-(j-1)*useSymFlag
             matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j)+dot_product(matrixInt(i,j,1:maxPoles),factor(1:maxPoles))
         enddo
      enddo
      call ExtendBySymmetry2(matrix)

    end

    !=================================================================================
    SUBROUTINE ExtendBySymmetry2(matrix)
          use NAGmodule
          COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit) :: matrix
          integer k,i,j,l,m


    if ((PBCflag==1).AND.(useSymFlag==1)) then
          do i=2,nsit
            matrix(2:nsit,i)=matrix(1:nsit-1,i-1)
            matrix(1,i)=matrix(nsit,i-1)
          enddo
    else if ((PBCflag==0).AND.(useSymFlag==1)) then
          do j=1,nsit/2
            do i=j,nsit-j+1
              matrix(j,i)=matrix(i,j)
              matrix(nsit-i+1,nsit-j+1)=matrix(i,j)
             matrix(nsit-j+1,nsit-i+1)=matrix(i,j)
            enddo
          enddo
    end if

    end

    !=================================================================================
    SUBROUTINE ExtendBySymmetry(matrix)
          use NAGmodule
          COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit) :: matrix
          integer k,i,j,l,m


    if ((PBCflag==1).AND.(useSymFlag==1)) then
          do i=2,nsit
            matrix(i,2:nsit)=matrix(i-1,1:nsit-1)
            matrix(i,1)=matrix(i-1,nsit)
          enddo
    else if ((PBCflag==0).AND.(useSymFlag==1)) then
          do i=1,nsit/2
            do j=i,nsit-i+1
              matrix(j,i)=matrix(i,j)
              matrix(nsit-i+1,nsit-j+1)=matrix(i,j)
              matrix(nsit-j+1,nsit-i+1)=matrix(i,j)
            enddo
          enddo
    end if

    end


    !=================================================================================

          SUBROUTINE NAGdiag(nsit1)
          use NAGmodule

          real*8,  allocatable :: WORK(:)
          integer, allocatable :: IWORK(:)  

          CHARACTER JOB, UPLO
          EXTERNAL dsyevd
          NMAX=nsit1
          LDA=NMAX
          LWORK=4*NMAX*NMAX+100
          LIWORK=5*NMAX
          LIWORK=10*NMAX      
          ALLOCATE(WORK(LWORK),IWORK(LIWORK))

          JOB='V'    
          UPLO='L' 

          CALL dsyevd(JOB,UPLO,nsit1,hmat,LDA,eval,WORK,LWORK,IWORK,LIWORK,INFO)

          IF (INFO.GT.0) THEN
          WRITE (*,*) 'Failure to converge.'
          stop
         endif

          deALLOCATE(WORK,IWORK)

          return
          end`
```

Comment: The computation code in the first snippet and in the subroutine seems to.be different.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `call ExtendBySymmetry(matrix)` in the subroutine?

Comment: yes, sorry another typo

Comment: I added a minimal example you can run. You need also llapack

Comment: And it seems that the ratio between the two timings decreases increasing the dimension of the matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to several edits of the original question, the answer is partially superfluous by now. However, the optimization part is still valid.

The real issue with you code is that you are passing `z` as a complex number to the subroutine (`omegaComplex`), while `omega(k)` is real. This results in the exponentiation and division being performed as complex operations instead of real ones.

Fixing `z` to be real (and `factor` in the optimization as well) leads to the expected results. With optimizations I get:

```
 time with subroutine  0.24000001139938831     
 time main  0.35700001695659012
```

---

Original answer:

First of all, the subroutine does not do the same operations that your inline code does. The operation `**matrixPol(k,3)` is the power to a complex number which involves a heavy computational effort. No wonder the subroutine is a lot slower.

I see a few possibilities to accelerate your code:

- The divisor `(z-matrixPol(k,1))**matrixPol(k,3)` is independent of `i` and `j` and can be taken out of the loop.
- Divisions are more expensive than multiplications. Therefore, you should pre-compute `factor = 1/div` outside the loop, and multiply with `factor` in the loop.
- The comparison `(matrixPol(k,2)/=0)` will almost never be true, unless you set the corresponding values to exactly zero. I assume you know the order of your poles before you call the subroutine, so why not pass it along and save yourself this comparison? If that is not possible, determine the number of poles inside the subroutine before the main loop. Then, the inner loop over `k` is much simpler.
- Inside the loop, you convert the input matrix to `real` over and over again. This can be done outside the loop in one go. Or, even better, just pass only the real part to the function!

At this point your code looks something like:

```
!=============================================================================
SUBROUTINE EvaluateFunc(matrixPol,matrixInt,z,matrix)
      use NAGmodule
      integer i,j,k
      REAL*8, DIMENSION(Npoles,3) :: matrixPol
      COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit,Npoles) :: matrixInt
      COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit) :: matrix
      COMPLEX*16 :: z, factor(Npoles)
      REAL*8, DIMENSION(nsit,nsit,Npoles) :: matrixInt_re
      integer :: maxPoles

  ! Determine maximum number of poles
  do k=1,Npoles
    ! Only valid if the poles are set to exactly zero outside. If not, 
    ! use ( abs(matrixPol(k,2)) <= someEpsilon ) 
    if ( matrixPol(k,2) == 0 ) then
      maxPoles = k-1
      exit
    endif
  enddo

  ! Pre-compute factors
  factor(:maxPoles) = (1.,0.)/(z-matrixPol(:maxPoles,1))**matrixPol(:maxPoles,3)
  ! Convert input to real
  matrixInt_re = real(matrixInt)

  do i=1,indCompMax
     do j=i,nsit-i+1 
       do k=1,maxPoles
         matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j)+matrixInt_re(i,j,k)*factor(k)
       enddo
     enddo
  enddo
  call ExtendBySymmetry(Gmat)    
end
```

Further optimization:

- Rewriting the code like this it becomes apparent that the inner loop over `k` is nothing more than a dot product. This could potentially be sped up by the compiler. The main loop would then look like:

```
  do i=1,indCompMax
     do j=i,nsit-i+1 
       matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j) + &
         dot_product( matrixInt_re(i,j,:maxPoles), factor(:maxPoles) )
     enddo
  enddo
```

- As [chw21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36111553/2737715) noted, Fortran uses a [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) memory layout and you are accessing it in a row major fashion. This potentially loses you a lot of memory. You should consider transposing your arrays in the main program or at least switch the loops over `i` and `j`. I would prefer the first option, as the inner dot product would then be performed on contiguous memory chunks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First, the operation  `**matrixPol(k,3)` is present also in the main code, I forgot to write it in the post.

Comment: @user3368447 Apart from adding the exponentiation in the main code, you also changed the number of iterations in the inner function of the subroutine. I suspect that this also changes the timings. Could you repeat the comparison?

Comment: yes sorry, also the different iteration was a typo in the post. The timings are obtained with the same iterations over i and j

Comment: The problem is that sometimes I have to pass to the subroutine a complex value for z (not in the example shown). So I imagine that I cannot reduce further the computation time

Comment: @user3368447 Make two subroutines, one with complex argument, and one with a real one. If you are feeling fancy, you can additionally use an interface to have them share the same name :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to see whether you can swap the loops around. Since Fortran stores the arrays in the order

```
(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), ..., (n, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), ...
```

Memory access is far faster if you loop along that dimension.